# KdTree (SciPy) consumes too much memory with 1024 dimensions

Tags: scipy, kdtree

My understanding of the memory of a kdtree is that the space needed should only depend on the leaf size and the number of samples.
I've tried out two different vectors one with 470 dimensions and another one with 1024 dims. Using the 1024 dims my RAM goes up to 10 GB!
Anybody could explain what is going on/or where the bug is?

Here is my code (im using a trained CNN, get it's descriptors and feed it into a kd-tree)

This is the numpy.shape output: Desc Shape:  (26235, 1024)

```
#Build the kdtree with Drive A descriptors
print "Building tree"
sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)
tree = spatial.KDTree(desc) #(Number of samples,K-dims) array
print "Finished building the tree"
```

Comment: FWIW Have you tried Scikit-learn's [`sklearn.neighbors.KDTree`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html)? I've used it with 1024 dim vectors without it eating all my memory (~10,000 samples IIRC).

Comment: nope not yet. So are you confirming that the sciPy implementation consumes much more memory?

Comment: No, I've not used SciPy's `spatial.KDTree` so can't comment on that I'm afraid...